# Specify over-the-counter medication in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is it possible to specify in FHIR R4 that a medication is available over-the-counter, as self-medication? In Medication and MedicationKnowledge there don't seem to be any options for indicating that a medication can be purchased without a doctor's recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MedicationKnowledge.productType should work.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using productType with the UMLS codes C0013231 and C0304227 to distinguish between over-the-counter and prescription drugs.